# c++: public private error

Tags: c++, private, public

so i've got this problem.
i want to get some variables from a diferant class then main and i've lerned that it's good to 
hide your data so it wont get so easely changed and use a getXXX function to acces it.
I tried to use the **private:** and **public:** thing but  when i do i get an error saying

*error: expected unqualified-id befor 'private'*

i got class nr1# called **dialog** and the class with the variables is called **race** (not as in black and white)

anyway i call the function like this:**(class dialog)**

```
    above this is all the #include stuff
    dialog::dialog(int y)
    {
        race raceO;
       switch(y)
       {

    case 1: cout << "choose a class \n1     ELF = " << raceO.getStats(1.1) << endl;
break:
}
```

and this is the race class

//were am i supposed to put 
private: and public:

```
    include "race.h"
    include <iostream>
    include <string>

    using namespace std;



    race::race(){
    }

    int race::raceElf(){
    return 0;
    }

        int attack = 5;
        int defence = 3;
        int stamina = 6;


    int race::getStats(int x){

    if(x == 11){
      return attack;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code and be (minimal) complete

Comment: Could you please add also your header?

Answer (score 0):

in the Class declaration it should look like

```
class myClass{
public:
myClass();
private:
double x,y,z;
}
```

that is how you should use public and private, but otherwise I can't see what is wrong, plase provide the header file or the class declaration.

Comment: lets see if this i a better asked question: were am i supposed to put my public and private thanks in advanced :)

Comment: in your header file, sorry it took so long

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to use your class. I would keep all your data members private. Methods `raceElf()` and `getStats()` should be public as you will call them on your object. If a method were used only within other class methods but not outside it should be private. Constructor must be public if you want to create any objects of your class.

```
class race{
public:
    race();
    int raceElf();
    int getStats(int);
private:
    int attack;
    int defence;
    int stamina;
}

race::race(){
    attack = 5;
    defence = 3;
    stamina = 6;
}

int race::raceElf(){ return 0;  }

int race::getStats(int x){
        if(x == 11){
            return attack;
        }
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: basecly i need my variables to be private ( thanks for the quick response i haven't read it yet :)

Comment: lets see if this i a better asked question:

were am i supposed to put my public and private

thanks in advanced :)